# Visual Studio 2013: F2 selects only filename not the extension

Tags: visual-studio-2013

In VS 2013, In Solution Explorer, if I select a file, say test.aspx, and hit F2 only **test** gets selected and not ".aspx". I want the complete filename to be selected. How can I do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not this the default behavior in Windows as well?

Comment: How can I change this default behavior on Windows. May be if I change in Windows, it might reflect in VS 2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an autohotkey script.

For more details, take a look here: https://superuser.com/questions/114869/select-full-file-name-when-renaming-on-windows-7